# Differenzierte Übersetzung für "ill" und "sick"

Tags: english-to-german

Beides lässt sich mit "krank" übersetzen, aber wie schaut es mit Sätzen aus, in denen beide vorkommen und eine leicht andere Bedeutung haben, die wichtig für den Satz ist?

Comment: Das hängt davon ab, ob wir von U-Englisch oder Non-U-Englisch sprechen, siehe [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/sick-or-ill/17012#17012).

Comment: Ist das nicht eher eine Frage für ein Forum, das sich mit englischer Sprache befasst?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Im Englischen sind *sick* und *ill* weitgehend miteinander austauschbar. Wenn ich es aber richtig verstanden habe, dann sehen es Engländer und Amerikaner unterschiedlich voneinander.

**Amerikaner** meinen mit *sick* eine Art Übelkeit und wer *ill* ist, ist wirklich krank. **Briten** hingegen meinen ein körperliches Gebrechen, wenn sie *ill* sagen und Übelkeit oder ein Magenleiden, wenn sie *sick* verwenden.

Auf Deutsch könnte man z. B. die Wörter also je nach kultureller (US/UK) Herkunft mit "**übel**" bzw. "**krank**" übersetzen.

Comment: Zu beachten ist hier die Grammatik: "Mir ist übel/schlecht." versus "Ich bin krank."

Answer (score 6):

Dass sich 'sick' bei den Briten auf Übelkeit bezieht, sieht man auch daran, dass in der Alltagssprache 'sicking up' für erbrechen benutzt wird.

Zum Beispiel könnte ein Satz wie:

> Yesterday I felt kind of ill, today
>   I'm sick too.

Übersetzt werden mit:

> Gestern hab ich mich den ganzen Tag
>   irgendwie schlecht gefühlt, heute ist
>   mir dazu auch noch übel.

Comment: Antwort beantwortet nicht die Frage.

Comment: @Jan: Naja, der zweite Teil enthält schon eine implizite Antwort – wenn sie auch ausführlicher und expliziter hätte sein können.

Answer (score 2):

Using the below definitions as a reference I'd say:

> Because he was affected by the illness Malaria, he was feeling sick
>   every day for about a year, when he started becoming ill.
>
> Weil er von der Krankheit Malaria befallen war, fühlte er sich
>   schlecht den ganzen Tag, seit einem Jahr als er anfing krank zu
>   werden.
>   Or in better German: Weil er von der Krankheit Malaria befallen war, fühlte er sich seit einem Jahr, als er begann krank zu werden, den ganzen Tag lang über schlecht.

-> sick --> schlecht/krank fühlen
-> ill --> krank sein
You can be ill but not feel sick. And vice versa. I.e. drinking to much alcohol can make you feel sick but you are not infected by an illness. Yet alcoholism can be an illness if you over do it.

The below definitions are from the built in dictionary of OS X 10.8.

> **Illness**: a disease or period of sickness affecting the body or mind: he died after a long illness | I've never missed a day's work through illness.
>
> **Sickness**: 1 the state of being ill: she was absent through sickness.
>   • [ often with adj. or noun modifier ] a particular type of illness or disease: botulism causes fodder sickness of horses | a woman suffering an incurable sickness.
>   2 the feeling or fact of being affected with nausea or vomiting: she felt a wave of sickness wash over her | travel sickness.

Comment: Your translation should rather be something along: "Weil er von der Krankheit Malaria befallen war, fühlte er sich seit (dem Tag, an dem) er krank geworden war(,) (für) ein Jahr lang jeden Tag schlecht."

Comment: No longer used to speaking German...

Comment: I'd like to add an apart. Your German sentence clearly indicates that he becomes ill exactly one year to the day before (he probably died today or a couple of days ago), whereas your English sentence does not necessarily indicates that. Your English sentence might talk about someone who is already dead for several years and you recollect the circumstances of the illness (which was what I understood when I read first). This is because in German you can differentiate by using "für" or "seit" while in English you use "for" in both cases. Adding "now" in the English sentence makes it more clear.

Comment: I don't feel crazy about this anyways, just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

"Because he was affected by the illness Malaria, he was feeling sick every day for about a year, when he started becoming ill."

Die vorgeschlagen Übersetzungen sind aber an sich nur sehr grob und interlinear; eine stilistisch angemessene Übersetzung wäre etwa:

Weil er sich mit Malaria angesteckt hatte, fühlt er sich, nachdem die Krankheit ausgebrochen war, fast ein Jahr lang jeden Tag schlecht/krank.

Noch besser würde man den Satz im Deutschen auflösen und sagen:

Er hatte sich mit Malaria angesteckt. Nachdem die Erkrankung einsetzte, ging es ihm über ein Jahr hinweg täglich schlecht.

Comment: Welche vorgeschlagene Übersetzungen? Die Frage frägt explizit nach Übersetzungen, sie schlägt selbst (außer dem allgemeinen *krank)* gar keine vor?